# Android radio button center above text

Tags: android, radio-button, center, radio-group

I have 4 radio buttons. Under these buttons i want a text. The radio buttons should be in the center above the text. i tried to put them in a linear layout together (text and button) but then i loose the function of the radio group because the radio buttons must be the direct children of the radio group. How can i do this?

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_timeline"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seek_timeline_morning"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/timeline_morning" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seek_timeline_noon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/timeline_noon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seek_timeline_evening"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/timeline_evening" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seek_timeline_night"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/timeline_night" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: use relative layout so you can position all your elements accordingly

Comment: use `android:gravity=center_horizontal`

Comment: @SatineKainne
Should i use the Relative Layout instead of mine Linear or a new relative around my radiogroup and the linear layout?

Comment: why not use relative layout to position the text in relation with the radio buttons and use relative layout to position your radio buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a relative layout into the linear layout and place the radio buttons inside!

I always use relative layout, it is much more adaptive when you get used to the controls.